# Slide a fragment up and down on swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am following [this](https://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/) tutorial to swipe my fragment up and down on swipe. But somehow swiping down animation is not working, fragment is staying at same position. Swiping up animation is working fine.I have put the animation on my childFragment

Below is my fragment xml:

```
<com.xyz.utils.SlidingRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout_discovery"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_level_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchview_style"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:defaultQueryHint="Search" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_new_discover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_credit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/color_txtWhite"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_intro_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="Walk through makeup tutorial side-by-side your face!"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.xyz.SlidingRelativeLayout>

Below is the custom sliding layout:
public class SlidingRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private float yFraction = 0;

    public SlidingRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlidingRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = null;

    public void setYFraction(float fraction) {

        this.yFraction = fraction;

        if (getHeight() == 0) {
            if (preDrawListener == null) {
                preDrawListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
                        setYFraction(yFraction);
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
            }
            return;
        }

        float translationY = getHeight() * fraction;
        setTranslationY(translationY);
    }

    public float getYFraction() {
        return this.yFraction;
    }
}
```

In my parent fragment I am making fragment animation like this:

```
public class MirrorFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mirror, null);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getContext();
        fragment = (MirrorFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mirror_frag");
        initViews(view);
//        setWidthOfBottomContainer();

        isUp = false;
        currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // Landscape
            cameraView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
                @Override
                public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    super.onSwipeLeft();
                    onSlideLeftViewButtonClick();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "swipe left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeRight() {
                    super.onSwipeRight();
                    onSlideLeftViewButtonClick();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "swipe right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Portrait
            cameraView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
                @Override
                public void onSwipeUp() {
                    super.onSwipeUp();

                    onSlideViewButtonClick();

                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams up_arrowParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) up_arrow.getLayoutParams();
                    up_arrowParams.verticalBias = 0.45f; // here is one modification for example. modify anything else you want :)
                    up_arrow.setLayoutParams(up_arrowParams);

                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams recorder = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) iv_record.getLayoutParams();
                    recorder.verticalBias = 0.45f; // here is one modification for example. modify anything else you want :)
                    iv_record.setLayoutParams(recorder);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "swipe up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeDown() {
                    super.onSwipeDown();

                    onSlideViewButtonClick();

                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams up_arrowParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) up_arrow.getLayoutParams();
                    up_arrowParams.verticalBias = 0.90f; // here is one modification for example. modify anything else you want :)
                    up_arrow.setLayoutParams(up_arrowParams);

                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams recorder = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) iv_record.getLayoutParams();
                    recorder.verticalBias = 0.90f; // here is one modification for example. modify anything else you want :)
                    iv_record.setLayoutParams(recorder);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "swipe down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        }


        up_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onSlideViewButtonClick();
            }
        });



        iv_record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCapturingVideo){
                    stopVideo();
                }else{
                    captureVideo();
                }

            }
        });

        cameraView.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoTaken(File video) {
                super.onVideoTaken(video);
                Log.d("Video_path", video.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                super.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onZoomChanged(float newValue, float[] bounds, PointF[] fingers) {
                super.onZoomChanged(newValue, bounds, fingers);
            }
        });


    }

    private void setWidthOfBottomContainer() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // code for portrait mode
            param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) height / 2);
            param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            // mDraggingPanel.setLayoutParams(param);
        } else {
            // code for landscape mode
            param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) width / 2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            //mDraggingPanel.setLayoutParams(param);
        }
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {

        btn_control = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_control);
        slidingView = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_drawer);
        frameContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.frame_video);
        cameraView = view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        up_arrow = view.findViewById(R.id.up_arrow);
        iv_record = view.findViewById(R.id.record);
        cameraView.setLifecycleOwner(fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner());
        cameraView.mapGesture(Gesture.PINCH, GestureAction.ZOOM); // Pinch to zoom!
        toLandAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.view_to_landscape);
        toPortAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.view_to_portrait);
        childFragment = new DiscoveryFragment();
       /* FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottom_up, R.anim.bottom_down);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("parent_fragment", "mirror_frag");
        childFragment.setArguments(args);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, childFragment,"discovery_frag");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();*/

    }

    private void toggleList() {

        Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("discovery_frag");
        if (f != null) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottom_up, R.anim.bottom_down,R.anim.bottom_up,R.anim.bottom_down);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("parent_fragment", "mirror_frag");
            childFragment.setArguments(args);
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, childFragment,"discovery_frag");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            try {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cameraView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraView.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraView.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMultiWindowModeChanged(boolean isInMultiWindowMode) {
        super.onMultiWindowModeChanged(isInMultiWindowMode);

    }

    private void getHeightWidth() {
       /* draggingPanelHeight = mLayout.getHeight();
       draggingPanelWidth = mLayout.getWidth();*/
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    }


    private void captureVideo() {
        if (cameraView.getSessionType() != SessionType.VIDEO) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't record video while session type is 'picture'.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (mCapturingVideo) return;
        mCapturingVideo = true;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Recording started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // message("Recording for 8 seconds...", true);
        cameraView.startCapturingVideo(CommonUtilities.getVideoFilePath("lips"));
        iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.recording_on);

    }


    private void stopVideo() {
        if (cameraView.getSessionType() != SessionType.VIDEO) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't stop record video while session type is 'picture'.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // message("Can't record video while session type is 'picture'.", false);
            return;
        }
        if (mCapturingVideo) {
            cameraView.stopCapturingVideo();
            iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.recording_off);
            if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
                mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity(), "makeup");
            }
//            recorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Recording stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCapturingVideo = false;
        }

    }


    private String getVideoFilePath(Context context, String name) {
        name = "smartmirror";
        final File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        return (dir == null ? "" : (dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/")) + name + VIDEO_EXTENSION;
    }
    // slide the view from below itself to the current position



    //TODO remove hardcoded height with the 50% of the screen
    public void onSlideViewButtonClick() {


        if (isUp) {
      /*      Animation bottomdown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    R.anim.bottom_down);
           // CommonUtilities.slideDown(slidingView);
            slidingView.startAnimation(bottomdown);
            slidingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
            toggleList();
           // slidingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            /*Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    R.anim.bottom_up);
           // CommonUtilities.slideUp(slidingView);
            slidingView.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            slidingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            toggleList();
            //slidingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        isUp = !isUp;
    }

    public void onSlideLeftViewButtonClick() {
        if (isUp) {
            CommonUtilities.slideToRight(slidingView);
        } else {
            CommonUtilities.slideToLeft(slidingView);

        }
        isUp = !isUp;
    }


}
```

The two animation class are :
bottom_down:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="yFraction"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>

</set>
```

bottom_up:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="yFraction"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0.5"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I followed what exactly said in the tutorial. Can someone tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: No error just sliding down animation is not working.